# Найти строки с одинаковыми id между собой в sql

Tags: sql

имеется таблица где первый столбец это ID, а вторая start_date и третья end_date.

| id | star_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 01.05.2021 | 02.05.2021 |
| 284 | 15.05.2021 | 17.06.2021 |
| 331 | 16.05.2021 | 21.05.2021 |
| 121 | 22.06.2022 | 15.05.2023 |

необходимо найти все строки с одинаковыми ID

Comment: Таблица с одинаковым id - уже не верное решение проектирования (если это ид текущей таблицы)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский айдишки тут условные, для упрощения описания я указал простые айди. Суть в том что мне нужно вытащить все записи у которых айди повторяется

Comment: Вытащить что-то или сравнить? Определитесь пожалуйста. Айдишиники условные или всё же записи где Id одинаковые? Про одинаковые id таблицы я написал. В итоге задача совершенно пространная

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все записи где айди одинаковые, то есть может существовать 4 записи с айди 555 и 9 записей с айди 396. Вот их и нужно мне вытащить)) Селект на один айди умею делать. Спасибо за замечание про сравнение, это сейчас исправлю в описании

Comment: Покажите требуемый результат для показанного примера данных.

Comment: @Akina к примеру две строки с айди 121 и его датами, 4 строки с айди 555 и 9 строк с айди 396 и их датами соответсвенно. В комментах таблицу начертить не получилось, мало обращаюсь к стаковерфлоу

Comment: Факты добавляют не в комментарии, а в текст вопроса как дополнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашёл.

```
SELECT * FROM 'table'
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM 'table' 
GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

но этот код выдает и одиночные записи у которых нет дубликата по столбцу

Comment: Вместо `'searching_row'` у вас `'id'`, надеюсь? Тогда должно правильно работать.

Comment: да, искомый столбец. В данном случае адйи

Comment: Ну так исправьте код на соответствующий вашему случаю. И ещё раз проверьте. Должно работать.

Comment: @CrazyElf уже исправил. Всё работает как часы))) всем спасибо за внимание. Вопрос смогу закрыть толькл через 2 дня. Хз почему, подсказка говорит что свой ответ как верный можно отметить только через 2 дня

Comment: В этом своём ответе тогда уж тоже исправьте на `id`, чтобы ответ был не просто примером, а решением вашей задачи

Comment: @МухаммадёрЖураев, свой ответ можно отметить как верный только через 2 дня, чтобы избежать накрутки.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов да) а вот причину долгого срока я не знал. Спасибо)